# Sending data from Server to Client with BLE and Python3

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

Do can anyone help me with my Problem?

I've got a Python-Client and a Python-Server. The Python-Client runs on PC-1 and the Server on PC-2. I would like to read out information about PC-2 on PC-1. At first i would like to get the MAC-Address of the PC-2. The thing is, that the Server already reacts on the client. But it doesn't send the information back to the client.

At first, here is the function of the Server-Code to return the MAC-Address.

```
# GetMacAdress   
class MACaddressCharacteristic(Characteristic):
    macUUID = "10001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

    def __init__(self, bus, index, service):
        Characteristic.__init__(
            self, bus, index, 
            self.macUUID, 
            ["read"], 
            service)

    def ReadValue(self, options):
        print("MAC-Adress-Function getting cast by client...")
        return [ 'Test' ]
```

The Output of the Server-Code on the Terminal of PC-2:

```
root@emblinux:/tmp# python3 Agent_creator.py 
Enter the name under which you want to find the device:GATEway
2023-11-14 12:12:04,381 - __main__ - INFO - Registering GATT application...
GetManagedObjects
org.bluez.GattService1 interface implementation
UUID of properties: 10001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Primary of properties: True
get back path: /org/bluez/example/service1
get back path: /org/bluez/example/service1
2023-11-14 12:12:04,417 - __main__ - INFO - GetAll
2023-11-14 12:12:04,419 - __main__ - INFO - returning props
2023-11-14 12:12:04,426 - __main__ - INFO - GATT application registered
2023-11-14 12:12:04,429 - __main__ - INFO - Advertisement registered
MAC-Adress-Function getting cast by client...
```

Every time the Client asks for the MAC-Address, the Server-Code prints "MAC-Adress-Function getting cast by client...". So there must be a working BLE-connection between Client and Server. Why doesn't the server send the MAC address back to the client?

And this is the part of the Client which is asking for the MAC-Address:

```
async def talk_to_device(deviceAddress):

    async with BleakClient(deviceAddress) as client:
        await client.is_connected()

        # Set up the main loop.
        DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
        global bus
        bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        global mainloop
        mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()

        om = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, '/'), DBUS_OM_IFACE)
        objects = om.GetManagedObjects()
        chrcs = []

        # List characteristics found
        for path, interfaces in objects.items():
            if GATT_CHRC_IFACE not in interfaces.keys():
                continue
            chrcs.append(path)
    
        # List sevices found
        for path, interfaces in objects.items():
            if GATT_SERVICE_IFACE not in interfaces.keys():
                continue

            chrc_paths = [d for d in chrcs if d.startswith(path + "/")]

            if process_di_service(path, chrc_paths):
                break

        if not svcUUID:
            print('No Device Service found')
            sys.exit(1)

        while True:
            print("______________________________________________________________________")
            print("Which information do you want?:")
            print("1: Device MAC-Address")
            print("2: Device name")
            print("3: serial number")
            print("4: ip-address")
            print("else:")
            print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")
            print("5: newConnection")
            print("6: close")
            print("______________________________________________________________________")
            command = input("type 1,2,3,4,5 or 6: ")
            print("______________________________________________________________________")
            
            if command == "1":
                print("Asking for Mac-Address...")
                macUUID[0].ReadValue({}, reply_handler=mac_cb,
                                    error_handler=generic_error_cb,
                                dbus_interface=GATT_CHRC_IFACE)
            elif command == "2":
                print("Asking for Device-Name...")
                print("Code")
            elif command == "3":
                print("Asking for Serial-Number...")
                print("Code")
            elif command == "4":
                print("Asking for IP-Adress...")
                print("Code")
            elif command == "5":
                return True
            elif command == "6":
                closingProgram()
            else:
                print("Invalid command")
                continue
```

Here is the output of the terminal on PC-1 i get, if i run the Client-Code:

```
ssv@jsz:~/Documents/Praxisphase/ProjektEmbededSystemConfigurationApp/BluetoothConnectionViaBluez$ sudo python3 client.py 
Searching for devices....
______________________________________________________________________
1: name:60-21-CA-FC-64-A8 | address: 60:21:CA:FC:64:A8
2: name:55-8B-98-49-5F-F0 | address: 55:8B:98:49:5F:F0
3: name:47-CC-0E-74-C0-36 | address: 47:CC:0E:74:C0:36
4: name:GATEway | address: 94:54:93:56:57:8C
5: name:D1-8F-34-77-62-6F | address: D1:8F:34:77:62:6F
6: name:EE-6B-EB-56-F4-29 | address: EE:6B:EB:56:F4:29
______________________________________________________________________
7: rescan
8: close
Name the device you want to connect with, (type number): 4
/home/ssv/Documents/Praxisphase/ProjektEmbededSystemConfigurationApp/BluetoothConnectionViaBluez/client.py:106: FutureWarning: is_connected has been changed to a property. Calling it as an async method will be removed in a future version
  await client.is_connected()
Device Information Service found: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_94_54_93_56_57_8C/service008d
______________________________________________________________________
Which information do you want?:
1: Device MAC-Address
2: Device name
3: serial number
4: ip-address
else:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
5: newConnection
6: close
______________________________________________________________________
type 1,2,3,4,5 or 6: 1
______________________________________________________________________
Asking for Mac-Address...
```

As you can see, the client casts the function for asking for the MAC-Address, but it doesn't get the MAC-Address back.

Does anyone have a idea, how i can solve this problem?

Comment: first: I don't see where you return MAC in server. Your `ReadValue` sends only `return ['Test']`. Second: if you get value then you have to assign to variable `variable = macUUID[0].ReadValue(...)` and later `print(variable)` or directly print  it `print( macUUID[0].ReadValue(...) )`. Without `print()` you can't see value.

Comment: At first:
I know, it is only a test, if the function returns this String, i will change it, that it will returning the MAC-Address. But at first, i would like to solve the problem, that it doesn't send the content, back.

Second:
I changing the MAC-Function on Client side:
'
                print("Asking for Mac-Address...")
                mac=macUUID[0].ReadValue({}, reply_handler=mac_cb,
                                    error_handler=generic_error_cb,
                                dbus_interface=GATT_CHRC_IFACE)
                print(mac)
'
And the output is "None"

Comment: How can i change code in a command to a code block?

Comment: And thank you for help

Comment: it is strange that you get `None` if `ReadValue` has `return [ 'Test' ]`. But I don't have two computers with Bluetooth to test it. So I can't help more.

Comment: ok, but thx, that you tried it